# Registration form with automated welcome email in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello fellow programmers, I'm a beginner in PHP/MySQL/HTML and I'm trying to create a registration form which sends an email to the registered user once fully signed up. I'm very confused on how to structure this and I have just got PHPMailer working but I don't know to how integrate this into the controller in order for the user to receive an email once registered .

This is my code for the index.php also known as the controller:

```
<?php
require_once('SMTP.php');
require_once('PHPMailer.php');
require_once('Exception.php');

use \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mail=new PHPMailer(true); // Passing `true` enables exceptions

include 'form.html.php';

//insert new user
if (isset($_GET['addform']))
{
    include '../admin/includes/db.inc.php';
    try
    {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO author SET name = :name, email = :email, password = :password';
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindvalue(':name', $_POST['name']);
        $s->bindvalue(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $s->bindvalue(':password')
        if($s->execute()){
            //settings
            $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
            $mail->SMTPAuth=true; // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username=''; // SMTP username - CONFIDENTIAL 
            $mail->Password=''; // SMTP password - CONFIDENTIAL 
            $mail->SMTPSecure='ssl';
            $mail->Port=465;

            $mail->setFrom('noreply@gmail.com', 'Guest');

            //recipient
            $mail->addAddress('noreply@gmail.com', 'Customer');     // Add a recipient

            //content
            $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject='Registeration Successful';
            $mail->Body='Thank You for registering with us. We hope to see you soon! <b>Happy Cooking</b>';
            $mail->AltBody='This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    
            $mail->send(); 
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = 'Error with registration.';
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    $authorid = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    try
    {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO authorrole SET 
        authorid = :authorid, 
        roleid = :roleid';
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindvalue(':authorid', $authorid);
        $s->bindvalue(':roleid', 'User');
        $s->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = 'Error assigning selected role to user.';
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }
    header('Location:welcome.html.php');
}
```

This is the HTML Form:

```html
div class="container">
    <!-- Page Heading/Breadcrumbs -->
    <h1 class="mt-4 mb-3" style="text-align:center">Register</h1>

    <p style="text-align:center">Here you will be able to register. Happy Cooking!</p>
    </br>

    <div style="margin: auto; text-align:center;">
    <form action="?addform" method="post">
    <label for="name"><b> Full Name:</b></br><input type="text" name="name" style ="height:40px;width:250px;" required placeholder="Enter your Full Name!"></label><br />
    <br /><label for="email"><b>Email:</b></br><input type="email" name="email" style ="height:40px;width:250px;" required placeholder="Enter a valid email address"></label><br />
    </br><label for="password"><b>Password:</b></br><input type="password" name="password" id="password" style ="height:40px;width:250px;" required placeholder="Enter Password"></label>  </br>
    <br /><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="Register">
    </form>
  </div>

      <!-- /.container -->
  <?php include '../admin/includes/footer.inc.html.php';?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: I have edited it. Sorry for the confusion.